# If a group has a normal subgroup of order $d$ for every divisor $d$ of the order of the group then it is nilpotent

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory, nilpotent-groups

How do I prove this?

Let $G$ be a finite group. For every $d$ dividing $|G|$, there is a normal subgroup of order $d$. Then $G$ is nilpotent.

The proof in my notes says that clearly every Sylow subgroup is normal, and we should "apply" this fact. However I don't see why this implies $G$ is nilpotent.

Comment: This depends on which definition of nilpotent group you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If every Sylow subgroup is normal, then $G$ is the direct product of its Sylow subgroups. This is because the intersection of Sylow subgroups of different $p$ is trivial, because $p$ divides the order of any non trivial element of a $p$-group.

The direct product of nilpotent groups is nilpotent, and $p$-groups are nilpotent. So $G$ is nilpotent.

Answer (score 1):

A finite group $G$ is nilpotent if and only all it’s Sylow subgroups are normal. Choose $d=$ highest prime power for each of the primes dividing $|G|$.

Comment: How to prove G is nilpotent if and only if all its Sylow subgroups are normal?

Comment: This is classical group theory knowledge, perhaps you have not had that in class but you will find it in any finite group theory book. Using Dummit & Foote? See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/24220/show-that-if-g-is-a-finite-nilpotent-group-then-every-sylow-subgroup-is-normal

Comment: That stack exchange question proves the wrong direction.

Comment: Not the wrong, but the more difficult direction. Every $p$-group is nilpotent and direct products of nilpotent groups are again nilpotent. I stop the discussion here, I suggest you show some effort of your own.

Comment: Thanks. I was missing the fact that direct products of nilpotent groups are nilpotent.

Comment: Ah! So you see! You learned something! Well done!