# Let $G$ a nilpotent group such that $10$ divides $|G|$. It is true that $G$ has element of order $10$?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory, nilpotent-groups

Let $G$ a nilpotent group such that $10$ divides $|G|$. It is true that $G$ has element of order $10$?

We know that $G$ can be expressed like  direct sum of Sylow's subgroups and that $G$ has a normal subgroup of order $10$ but how can we answer to this question?

Comment: So you mean a *finite* nilpotent group?

Comment: In fact, it has a central element of order $10$. The Sylow $2$-subgroup must contain a (central) element of order $2$, the Sylow $5$-subgroup must contain a (central) element of order $5$, and the two must commute, because the Sylow $2$-subgroup commutes elementwise with the Sylow $5$-subgroup.

Comment: Yes you're right.

Comment: @DonAntonio: If you talk about $10$ dividing the order, what else could it be?

Comment: I've heard of generalized Sylow subgroups and stuff, Arturo...in fact, within a seminar about infinite soluble and nilpotent groups and stuff.

Comment: Generalized Sylow is certainly a thing, but that's not what Arturo was saying -- $10\alpha = \alpha$ for any infinite cardinal $\alpha$, so every infinite group $G$ technically satisfies "$10$ divides $\lvert G \rvert$". At the same time, it's obvious that not every infinite group has an element of order $10$, so it's silly to pretend it's unclear that $G$ is meant to be finite in this question. I'm a big fan of precision and correctness, but your objection seemed overly pedantic.

Comment: @DonAntonio: It’s not about $p$-elements or $p$-subgroups, infinite nilpotent groups (I’m perfeclty happy to work with infinite nilpotent groups), or anything like that. We simply do not talk about a number dividing the order of an infinite group. That *never* happens.

Comment: The most important thing is that in the original post there was something that was supposed to be $\;10\,\mid\,|g|\;$ and I missed completely (it doesn't exist afther the post has been edited). That clears all fine.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Why are the statements you make in the first comment true?

Comment: @IgorRivin: Any finite $p$-group has nontrivial center, and by Cauchy’s Theorem, it has a central element of order $p$. And if $G=H_1\times H_2\times\cdots\times H_m$, then $Z(G)=Z(H_1)\times Z(H_2)\times\cdots\times Z(H_m)$. But even if you don’t know the fact about centers of $p$-groups, by Cauchy the $2$-Sylow has an element $x$ of order $2$, and the $5$-Sylow has an element $y$ of order $5$, and because $G=P_2\times P_2\times\text{(Sylows for other primes)}$, $xy=yx$. Then $|xy|=10$.

Comment: @DonAntonio: I rephrased that because the OP used a rather nasty `\bigg|` to denote “divides”. Seemed like the easiest way to deal with it.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Why is $G$ a product of Sylows? That is not at all obvious.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin The proof is contained here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nilpotent_group but it is not clear that the OP would be aware of it. You are an expert in nilpotent groups, others of us less so.

Comment: @IgorRivin: It is a feature of finite nilpotent groups (and the OP states they know it). A finite group is nilpotent if and only if it has a unique $p$-Sylow subgroup for every $p$, if and only if it is the product of its Sylow $p$-subgroups. I’ll grant that it is not obvious, and if the OP had not stated they already know it, I would not be cavalier about it. [Here’s a post asking about one direction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/24220/show-that-if-g-is-a-finite-nilpotent-group-then-every-sylow-subgroup-is-norma)

Comment: @ArturoMagidin fair enough.

Comment: @IgorRivin: The OP *states explicitly* “We know that $G$ can be expressed like direct sum of Sylow’s subgroups.” How does that **not** clearly indicate they are aware of it?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Since the sentence did not make strict sense to me, I ignored it. You know enough about the subject that you knew that some form of it DID make sense :)

Answer (score 1):

Since $G$ is a direct product of its Sylow subgroups, let us call its $2-$ and $5-$ Sylow subgroups $P_2$ and $P_5$.  They are non-trivial since $|G|$ is divisible by $10$.  Taking a non-identity element of $P_2$ and raising to an appropriate power, we have $g\in P_2$ with $o(g)=2$ and similarly we have $h \in P_5$ with $o(h)=5$.  But since $G = P_2 \times P_5 \times \mathrm{Stuff} $, all elements of $P_2$ commute with all elements of $P_5$, so $g$ and $h$ commute.  Therefore, $o(gh)=10$, so the answer is affirmative and $gh$ is the required element.

Answer (score 0):

There are elements of order  $5$ and $2$, by Cauchy.

If I can show those elements commute, then their product will have order $10$.

But nilpotency and finiteness imply that elements of relatively prime order commute.